# How do I organize an Array of objects according to the sum of its attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, sorting, object

I’m developing the backEnd part for a selling app in which I have 2 Array of Objects, one got the sellers' name, and the other has the monthly sales.
I was told by my superiors to order the Array of names from the one that made the most sales to the one that made the least ( from highest to lowest ) using the data from the array which contains the sales, basically making a summation of the key => quantity.
I’m not sure how to do it, I tried to use a Reduce method with the sales of each seller but I can’t think how to compare them to reorganize the Array.
The code is:

```
const sellers= [{id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},{id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},{id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}];

const sales= [{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 234},{equipo: 'italiano', sellerId: 3, quantity: 24},{equipo: 'polaco', sellerId: 1, quantity: 534},{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 1234},{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 3, quantity: 2342}];
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
const bestSellers= () => {
  sales.reduce((sum, value) => ( value.sellerId == 1 ? sum + value.area : sum), 0); }
```

The final result should look like this:

```
const sellers= [{id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45},{id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},{id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23}]
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: of course, this is what i have tried: const bestSellers= () => {
  sales.reduce((sum, value) => ( value.sellerId == 1 ? sum + value.area : sum), 0); }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your "final result" section is correct? That doesn't show anything about a sum.

Comment: Ya, because there's a relationship made with sellerId. The sum is made on quantity

Comment: One thing you can try, is to sum the quantity by sellerId within the sales array, and add that total to the related sellers array as a new field named something like total.  Then perform an array of objects sort on that new total field.  Then use the reverse() array function to get the final ordering from high to low.

Comment: Your example of reduce() does not look right with the hard coded filtering on `value.sellerId == 1`.  Aren't you limiting the reduce to only processing one seller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do two things here.

1. Find the total sales for each seller.
2. Sort the total sales for each seller.

Inside my sort function you can see I am filtering all of the sales by the seller.

Once I have just the sales for one seller I use the reduce method to sum the quantity of their sales into an easy to use number.

Then I'm comparing the previous sellers quantity to the current sellers quantity to re-order them using the sort method.

I encourage you to read the documentation of the methods used so you understand what is happening at each step.

Methods used:
[Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const sellers = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'juan',
  age: 23
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'adrian',
  age: 32
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'apolo',
  age: 45
}];

const sales = [{
  equipo: 'frances',
  sellerId: 2,
  quantity: 234
}, {
  equipo: 'italiano',
  sellerId: 3,
  quantity: 24
}, {
  equipo: 'polaco',
  sellerId: 1,
  quantity: 534
}, {
  equipo: 'frances',
  sellerId: 2,
  quantity: 1234
}, {
  equipo: 'frances',
  sellerId: 3,
  quantity: 2342
}];

const expected = [{
  id: 3,
  name: 'apolo',
  age: 45
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'adrian',
  age: 32
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: 'juan',
  age: 23
}]

const result = sellers.sort((a, b) => {
  totalA = sales.filter(sale => sale.sellerId === a.id).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.quantity, 0)
  totalB = sales.filter(sale => sale.sellerId === b.id).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.quantity, 0)
  return totalB - totalA
})

// Check we get what we expect
console.log(JSON.stringify(expected) === JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: It is not optimal to perform an Array#sort() and for each callbackFn predicate to execute Array#filter() and Array#reduce() 2 times respectively

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles Yes I know that but my goal was to show very explicitly how to do this so the questioner can understand the process. This code is very easy to read and should be a good first step for a beginner to understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

First, reduce the `sales` array to the sum of quantity for each seller, sort this list and then map to the respective seller from the `sellers` array.

```js
const sellers= [{id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},{id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},{id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}];

const sales= [{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 234},{equipo: 'italiano', sellerId: 3, quantity: 24},{equipo: 'polaco', sellerId: 1, quantity: 534},{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 1234},{equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 3, quantity: 2342}];

const bestSellers = (sellers, sales) => {
  let res = sales.reduce((result, sale) => {
    // Check if seller is already added in result
    const obj = result.find(s => s.sellerId === sale.sellerId);
    if (obj) {
      // If seller already added then increase it's quantity
        obj.quantity += sale.quantity;
    } else {
      // If seller not added, add seller in result
        result.push({ sellerId: sale.sellerId, quantity: sale.quantity });
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
    
  // Sort result by quantity in decreasing order 
  res.sort((a,b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
  
  // Map each sale to the seller
  res = res.map(s => sellers.find(seller => seller.id === s.sellerId));
    
  return res;
}

const result = bestSellers(sellers, sales);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that:

```js
const
  sellers = 
    [ { id: 1, name: 'juan',   age: 23 } 
    , { id: 2, name: 'adrian', age: 32 } 
    , { id: 3, name: 'apolo',  age: 45 } 
    ] 
, sales = 
    [ { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 2, quantity:  234 } 
    , { equipo: 'italiano', sellerId: 3, quantity:   24 } 
    , { equipo: 'polaco',   sellerId: 1, quantity:  534 } 
    , { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 2, quantity: 1234 } 
    , { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 3, quantity: 2342 } 
    ];


sellers.forEach( ({id},i,all) => // add a sum attribute 
  {
  all[i].sum = sales
                .filter(({sellerId})=>sellerId===id)
                .reduce((sum,{quantity})=>sum+quantity,0)
  });

sellers
  .sort( (a,b) => b.sum - a.sum)                 
  .forEach((seller,i,all) => delete seller.sum ) // remove the sum

console.log( sellers )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

or:

```js
const
  sellers = 
    [ { id: 1, name: 'juan',   age: 23 } 
    , { id: 2, name: 'adrian', age: 32 } 
    , { id: 3, name: 'apolo',  age: 45 } 
    ] 
, sales = 
    [ { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 2, quantity:  234 } 
    , { equipo: 'italiano', sellerId: 3, quantity:   24 } 
    , { equipo: 'polaco',   sellerId: 1, quantity:  534 } 
    , { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 2, quantity: 1234 } 
    , { equipo: 'frances',  sellerId: 3, quantity: 2342 } 
    ] 

// compute all the sum in a new Sums object:
const Sums = sales.reduce((sum,{sellerId : id, quantity}) =>
  ( sum[id] ??= 0, sum[id] += quantity , sum ), {} )

sellers .sort( (a,b) => Sums[b.id] - Sums[a.id])

console.log( sellers )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const sellers = [{ id: 1, name: 'juan', age: 23 },{ id: 2, name: 'adrian', age: 32 },{ id: 3, name: 'apolo', age: 45 },]
const sales = [{ equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 234 },{ equipo: 'italiano', sellerId: 3, quantity: 24 },{ equipo: 'polaco', sellerId: 1, quantity: 534 },{ equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 2, quantity: 1234 },{ equipo: 'frances', sellerId: 3, quantity: 2342 },]

const salesHash = sales.reduce((a, { sellerId, quantity }) => 
  (a[sellerId] = (a[sellerId] || 0) + quantity, a), {})

const result = sellers.sort((a, b) => 
  salesHash[b.id] - salesHash[a.id])

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```